# EF Core Scaffolding DB results in two classes for some tables

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I needed to scaffold the database tables of my database to my project so as usual, I ran:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=xxx;" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -OutputDir Database -f
```

But realised I was getting two classes for a couple of tables.

I have a table called Building and another called Appartment but the scaffold command created Building.cs, Building1.cs, Appartment.cs, Appartment1.cs.

The other tables were fine.

The only references to these tables are the ones within OnModelCreating in addition to other tables which have a FK to Building and Apartment. Fk's seem to not be present on the main classes (the ones without 1 appended).

I am using version 3.1.4:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.4">
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

I added audit tables for both of the tables in question under a different namespace. Completely forgot about them.